# What's the best practice to get user profile in RESTful API design

Tags: rest

In my case, each user has a profile with lots of attributes, e.g. gender, age, name. What's the best practice to design the RESTful API to get those attributes? The followings are possible solutions:

1. Get all attributes in a single call

   Get all attributes:
   Request: `GET http://api.domain.com/users/id/profile`

   Response: `{"name" : "Jim", "gender" : "male", "age" : 12}`
2. Get attribute one-by-one

   Get attributes list:

   Request: `GET http://api.domain.com/users/id/profile`

   Response: `{ "attributes" : ["name", "gender", "age"] }`

   Get a specified attribute:

   Request: `GET http://api.domain.com/users/id/profile/name`

   Response: `{"name" : "Jim"}`

With the first solution, the client gets all attributes in a single call. However, the problem is that **there's too many attributes, and we'll add more attributes to the profile**. I'm wondering which one is better?

Answer (score 2):

If you have lots and lots of attributes, another approach would be to group them.
In REST, everything needs to be a resource (for example, but not limited to, something identifiable by an URL).
So you could have

```
GET http://api.domain.com/users/id/profile
```

and you get

```
{ "categories" : ["names", "address", "interests", "jobhistory", "publications", "blogs", "skills"] }
```

and then you query further. That does imply multiple trips but you would not have to query the many attributes one by one, ending up with 50 queries out of 75 attributes, for example, but might need 3 queries to get the 50 attributes you want.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely the first option seems much better primarily because of saving multiple calls - mind you clients as well, it will be much easier for them to fetch what they need in a single call instead of calling - more or less - the same resources multiple times.

It seems that what are you looking for is called resource expansion - you can read about it e.g. [here](https://stormpath.com/blog/linking-and-resource-expansion-rest-api-tips).

In short it assumes that the response you send is configurable with query params. If no params are included some basic subset of attributes is returned. If params to be expanded are sent - the basic subset is returned along with other attributes listed in query param. You can also mix two approaches. Some of parameters might be expanded via query params other may be called as subresources - it depends arbitrarily on the *size* of a resource.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to divide user profile attributes into logical categories and make these categories available to your clients through query parameters like ...

```
names (array of names (aliases)) : first, last, middle, prefix
addresses (array of addresses) : street, apt, city, state, country, county
jobs (array of jobs) : company, designation, start_date, end_date, city, state, country
```

Provide an API that returns the up-to-date list of categories available on user profile as documentation can get outdated.

```
GET http://api.domain.com/users/profiles/categories
```

Response:

```
{
    "categories": ["names", "address", "interests", "jobs" ],
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "users.profiles.categories",
            "href": "http://api.domain.com/users/profiles/categories"
        }, {
            "rel": "users.profiles.category.names",
            "href": "http://api.domain.com/users/profiles?categories=names"
        }, {
            "rel": "users.profiles.category.addresses",
            "href": "http://api.domain.com/users/profiles?categories=addresses"
        }, {
            "rel": "users.profiles.category.interests",
            "href": "http://api.domain.com/users/profiles?categories=interests"
        }, {
            "rel": "users.profiles.category.jobs",
            "href": "http://api.domain.com/users/profiles?categories=jobs"
        }, {
            "rel": "users.profiles.category.all",
            "href": "http://api.domain.com/users/profiles?categories=all"
        }
    ]
}
```

With the above HATEOAS and depending on the categories mentioned in query parameter, your service can query those entities from database and form the response and return back to your client.

```
GET http://api.domain.com/users/id/profile?categories=names,address,interests,jobs
```

`NOTE:` if comma(`,`) cannot be not directly used in URL then you can use `%2C` (url-encoded value of `,`).

Additionally, your actual GET API can also return HATEOAS to sub categories if the user doesn't use the categories API to get all sub categories.

This is just one of the way where you can using additional informative end point provide available/supported categories (query parameters) and HATEOAS will help your client to navigate thru those available sub-categories.